# Provide REST API from Ionic App

Tags: rest, express, ionic-framework, ionic2

is it possible to provide a REST API from an Ionic App?
I tried to install express, to receive REST calls, but no luck so far.

Background is, that I want to call from one Ionic2 app a method of another Ionic2 app. 
I looked hours around but couldn't find a way to do such thing. I know this is not the common way, but it's necessary for my case, because it should replace push notifications in a quite dirty way (due to missing dev accounts and it's just for demonstration purpose)

Comment: Just to make sure., you are planning to create an ionic app, run it as a server to let other ionic 2 apps connect to it..?

Comment: yes, that's my plan

Comment: Are you sure bro..? I mean are you sure your mobile has the capacity to handle multiple requests as your user base increases..? Wouldn't it be wiser to provide your apps from a node server hosted on something like heroku maybe..?

Comment: Yes, it is only going to have one client, this client will call a method of the "server". This is just a workaround, because I currently don't have a dev account to use push notifications. 
The app is only for demonstration purpose, no prod version is planned yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the [Ionic Native httpd plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/httpd/)?  This may provide what you are looking for with a few tweaks

Usage example straight from their docs:

```
import { Httpd, HttpdOptions } from '@ionic-native/httpd';

constructor(private httpd: Httpd) { }

...


let options: HttpdOptions = {
     www_root: 'httpd_root', // relative path to app's www directory
     port: 80,
     localhost_only: false
 };

this.httpd.startServer(options).subscribe((data) => {
 console.log('Server is live');
});
```